# How to restart interrupted Jenkins jobs after a server or node failure/restart?

Tags: jenkins, docker-swarm

I'm running a Jenkins server and some slaves on a docker swarm that's hosted on preemptive google instances (akin to AWS spot instances). I've got everything set up so that at any given moment there is a Jenkins master running on a single server and slaves running on every other server on the swarm. When one server gets terminated another is spun up and replaces it, and eventually Jenkins is back up running again on another machine even if its server was stopped, and slaves get replaced as they die.

I'm facing two problems:

My first one is when the Jenkins master dies and comes back online it tries to resume the jobs that were previously running and they end up getting stuck trying to be built. Is there any way to automatically have Jenkins restart jobs that were interrupted instead of trying to resume them?

The second is when a slave dies I'd like to automatically restart any jobs that were running on it elsewhere. Is there any way to do that?

Currently I'm dealing with both situations by have an external application retry the failed build jobs, but that's not really optimal.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why does your master die? Seems like a IT nightmare when servers go down...

Comment: As I mentioned I'm running it on preemptive servers, which get terminated in at most 24 hours after being launched, so it will always get shut down and be restarted somewhere else (it stores its data on a shared storage that's visible from any node in the swarm).

Since everything's automated the environment as a whole is pretty resilient and we can afford any single component to go down, the only outstanding issue being these Jenkins jobs.